Page Not Found errors when clicking simulate this circuit on old answers
I am getting "Page Not Found" errors when clicking the "simulate this circuit" link below CircuitLab schematics in old answers.
The problem seems to be that the rendered page with the answer has a link with the old imgur.com address
<a href="/plugins/schematics?image=http...imgur.com...

even though, when one edits the page, the text that shows up in the edit window is of the form
![schematic](https://i.sstatic.net/....png)

It is as though there is a cached version of the page that does not match the version available in the edit window. However, the cached version is not on my local computer, as I have cleared the cache and the problem persists.
The link in a rendered page should look like
<a href="/plugins/schematics?image=https...isstatic.net...

with an isstatic.net address.
I have found a work-around. If one makes any (non-null) edit to the answer, it seems that the link will be updated to a working version.
Note that the version of the link in the edit history page has the correct isstatic.net address, even though the link in the current page for the question does not.
Broken Example | Correct Example

I'll have it looked at

Thanks, we missed this in the data migration because the URL in the simulate link is extra encoded (i.e. ?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fhKV31.png instead of http://i.stack.imgur.com/hKV31.png).
We can definitely update this without the workaround of making edits to thousands of posts, either via DB script or rebaking (our process of converting markdown to html) the posts to include the correct link.
We'll provide more updates soon

This has been fixed now. Our original update from Imgur Urls to the new Url domain were not looking at encoded Urls for schematics. Thanks for the report!
